# Can I trade a Steam game that I don't want?

Tags: steam

The title pretty much says it all. If someone gave me a game, and I opened it for a few minutes to take a gander, can I still trade it to someone else? Or is it forever mine? For example, if someone were to gift me a copy of DotA 2 (not that I don't like DotA, it's just an example), and I opened it to see what was in it, can I still gift it to someone else?

**Edit**: Follow-up question: Can I have an opened copy of game *X*, but still receive additional copies of game *X* if I am, say, the middle-man for a Secret Santa or something of the like?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's forever yours. Only gifts that have not been added to your Steam library can be traded.

Source: [Steam Support – Steam Trading](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6748-ETSG-5417#usedgames)

Comment: Is that the final answer? Nothing can be done? Can I trade it using Steam trade?

Comment: Yep, final answer. Lemme add the official source… there. And no, it can't be retraded.

Comment: D'oh! I knew I shouldn't have opened it. Oh well.

Comment: so what was the game? Dota 2?

Comment: However, when you open something you get asked whether to put it into your library or into your inventory. Picking the later will let you retrade it.

Comment: @Ullallullo Good nitpick—answer updated!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Unplayed doesn't give the right impression either since you can't trade unplayed stuff if your inventory. You should probably just mention the choice and stuff.

Comment: @JeffreyLin Follow-up questions should be posted as new questions. I don't know the answer, and someone else might, so it will really work much better on its own.

Answer (score 6):

On Steam, you have a **Library** and an **Inventory**.  Your Library is the list of games you own and can play, but can't trade; your Inventory is the list of games you can trade but can't play.

If you want to play a game in your Inventory, you can add it to your Library, but games can't move in the other direction - once a game is in your Library, it's there forever and can never be traded.

You can view your inventory by going to **Steam --> (Your Name) --> Inventory**.
To add a game from your inventory to your library, click on it, then choose "Add to my Game Library" on the right.

> ..and I opened [the gift] it to see what was in it.

There is no such concept as "opening" a Steam gift.  When you receive a gift, Steam tells you immediately what game you were sent, then gives you three options:

- **Add game to my Library.**  *(This lets you play the game, but not trade it)*
- <s>Add game to my Inventory.</s> *Steam removed this option in 2019*
- **Decline** *(Returns the game to the gifter)*

---

> Can I have an opened copy of game X, but still receive additional copies of game X

Assuming you mean *"If I have a game in my Library, can I also purchase/receive a second copy and put it in my Inventory?"* the answer is yes, there are no restrictions on the games you can have in your Inventory.

Answer (score 0):

If someone gifted you it and you've played is less than 2 hours and you've had it for less then 14 days it can be refunded but only under those circumstances. I got his of the steam help page