# How does the Steam Marketplace work?

Tags: steam

After the Trading Card update, I noticed an option that said "sell", and discovered the Steam Market. I was wondering, how does this work? When I clicked "Sell," it took me to a page asking me for the money I receive and the money the buyer pays.

Is the Steam Market an auctioning feature to auction Steam items? Is it a way to simply sell items?

Comment: Cynical response: It's basically a way for Valve to capitalize on their new *Steam Trading Cards* thing.  They take a cut from every card or item transaction made through the market.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it is a place to buy and sell virtual items.  At this time, only some in-game items *(including TF2 keys, the primary "currency" used in Steam trading)* and trading cards can be bought and sold - you cannot buy/sell copies of games in your [inventory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/100150/113914#113914).

Items are sold for a fixed price, chosen by the seller *(it is not an auction)*.  You can buy items from the market using the money in your Steam Wallet, or with paypal/credit card.  When you sell an item, the money gets put in your Steam Wallet. **There is no way to move that money to, say, your Paypal; it can only be used on Steam.**

Valve and the company behind the game each get a percentage of the final sale price, depending on the game (generally 5% for Valve, 10% for the game's creators, minimum one cent each); the seller gets the rest *(That is why there are two input boxes, one for "Buyer Pays" and one for "You Receive")*

You must have [Steam Guard](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4020-ALZM-5519) enabled to use the Market.

You can learn more at the [Steam Community Market FAQ](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6088-UDXM-7214).